# integral domain for set of integers

Tags: linear-algebra, integral-domain

*In an integral domain, a product is zero only when one of the factors is zero; that is, ab=0 only when a=0 or b=0.*
Can we do the following steps for proving set of integers an integral domain?
*let **a=3** and **b=0**

for all **a**,**b** belongs to integers

**a.b=3.0=0***
If not kindly show how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a.b=0$.

You have not shown that if $a.b=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$.